# Breadcrumbs issue in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

I have a Wordpress site and have a scenario where I am having issues getting the breadcrumbs showing the correct trail.

So basically I have a page called Plants, and in this page I am using Divi's Shop module to feature products from WooCommerce with a particular category.  When you select a particular plant from the plants page, you go to the plant details page from woocommerce.  However the trail shown in the breadcrumbs is wrong.  Instead of showing the following (for example):

Home > Garden Centre > Plants > Annuals > Begonia

It is showing this:

Home > Products > Begonia

If you click on Products it takes you to the WooCommerce shop page.  However I want that the users can go back to the previous page for example by using the trail from breadcrumbs.  In order to show breadcrumbs I am using the feature from Yoast SEO plugin.

Did anyone ever encounter this issue?  Is there a setting or something which I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available for this.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-breadcrumbs/

give it a look.

Comment: does this work also with non woo-commerce pages?  Will it show the breadcrumbs in other normal pages i have within the site?

Comment: installed but im not getting any breadcrumbs unfortunately.  Disabled Yoast breadcrumbs and I do not get anything, and if i enable the ones from Yoast i just get their breadcrumbs.  Do i need to add something to the template file in php where I need the breadcrumbs to be displayed?

Comment: yep done that, but still not showing up for some reason.  Checked in the source code and can't find it either.

Comment: I think the plugin's code conflicting with Yoast breadcrumbs. I have no idea here. you need to play with it. Try deleting Yoast breadcrumbs from your file system.

Comment: tough luck, disabled Yoast plugin but still not showing up.  Was wondering whether I should add some php in my template where I want the breadcrumbs to show, cos otherwise im not sure where it would try to add them by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have somehow achieved what I need by using Breadcrumb NavXT
https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

It gives you a lot of customisation options to update the breadcrumbs.